# The rank of the sum of outer products distributed according to a Haar measure

Tags: probability-theory, random-matrices

While working on the journal version of our paper, we encountered the following problem, which seems to be fairly simple but we could not find the answer:

Suppose $A_i \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$ are i.i.d. Gaussian matrices ($p<n$), and $A_i = V_i \Sigma_i U_i^T$ is the reduced SVD of the matrix. Then taking these $U_i$, we can form $\sum_{i=1}^m U_i U_i^T$. How large $m$ needs to be for this to be full rank?

I think the $U_i$ formed this way follow a Haar measure (meaning its uniformly distributed on Stiefold manifold).

Comment: I take it the $U_i$ are matrices. Is a "bunch" of matrices just a collection of matrices? And what does it mean to say that a bunch of matrices is a Haar measure?

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt reply! Yes $U_i$ are matrices. Yes it's a collection of matrices. My problem is like this: supper $A_i \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$ are i.i.d. Gaussian matrices ($p<n$), and $A_i = V_i \Sigma_i U_i^T$ is the reduced SVD of the matrix. Then taking these $U_i$, we can form $\sum_{i=1}^m U_i U_i^T$, and how large $m$ needs to be for this to be full rank?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry. But the version of the question in your comment makes a lot more sense to me than the version you originally posted. You might consider editing the question for clarity. (It's still totally unclear to me what this has to do with Haar measure...)

Comment: Thank you! I think the $U_i$ formed this way is a Haar measure (meaning its uniformly distributed on Stiefold manifold)

Answer (score 0):

To get  a full rank matrix, the size of m should be at least $p$.

Answer (score 0):

For every $i$, $U_i$ is a random pseudo-unitary $(n\times p)$ matrix; then $rank(U_iU_i^T)=p$. Moreover, the $(U_i)_i$ are iid; then the images of the $(U_iU_i^T)_i$ are in general position, that is $rank(\sum_{i=1}^m U_iU_i^T)=\inf(n,mp)$. Thus the required condition is $mp\geq n$.